# Which parts of the rails session object server side is actually written to the user's session cokie

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-5

We've been running into a cookie overflow issue, the cause is when a user creates a long query and then devise stores their location in the session, which is so long it causes a session overflow.

Rather than just resorting to clipping the stored location when it's too arbitrarily long, I'd like to see if there's other useless data I could clear but I'm not sure what part of `session` is actually written to the user's session cookie.

I've tried searching for this information but I just get back articles on the rails session itself, or about session's and so forth.

**Which parts of the `session` object is actually written to the end user's session cookie?**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to pull out the raw session cookie string and check if it's `bytesize` is greater then `4098`(4kb) like this:

```
session.instance_variable_get(:@req).instance_variable_get(:@env)['rack.request.cookie_hash']['_*app_name*_session'].bytesize > 4098
```